# Read file at startup Chrome extension/kiosk app

Tags: google-chrome, filesystems, google-chrome-app, kiosk

I'm currently developing my first Chrome app that we'll be used as a Kiosk app later.

I'm trying to read a file at the startup of the app, that file is a config file (.json). It contains values that will be passed inside a URL once the app has launched (ie: www.google.com/key=keyValueInTheJsonFile).

I used https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem (the method "chooseEntry" especially) to be able to read a file, but in my case I would like to directly specify the path/name of the file and not ask the user to select a file. Like that I can pass the values to the redirected URL at the startup.

Any idea of how I could possibly do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the [sandboxed filesystem](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) api.

Comment: Yep I used it but now when I try to read a file it says "NOT_FOUND_ERR". It means that it didn't find the file but this file exists in the root of my app "/". And even when I try to create a new file with "{create: true}“ it doesn't return any error as if the operation has succeeded but the file is never created every time I try. Do you know why? Bad permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your file is in the package you can read it using simple XHR or Fetch. 
You can't use web filesystem since it has different purpose and Chrome filesystem (user's FS) won't work here either since it needs a user interaction.

Use function [getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-getURL) to get a full URL to the resource and then make XHR call:

```
var rUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL('file.json');
fetch(rUrl).then((response) => {
  return response.json();
})
.then((fileContent) => {
  // the content
})
.catch((cause) => console.log(cause));
```

Comment: This solution works very well! But I would need the file that I want to read to be somewhere else than inside the app itself. I'm not sure if it's possible due to access restrictions and security... Do you know anything more about that?

Comment: It can be hosted in some server and you can download it from there (the same method, you need to declare host permission in the manifest file). But if you want to store the file on disk and take it from there you need a user interaction. You must open the open file dialogue and point to the file. You can persist this information and try to re-use this location when the app is next time loaded.
Check the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) for more information about how the filesystem works.

Comment: Yep that's what I thought! I'll do like that, select the file the first time and retain the entry (file+path) to be auto-loaded when the app restarts. Thanks!

Comment: And naturally the example above can be simplified to the form of: `fetch(rUrl).then((response) => response.json())`

Comment: Side note. for the package directory, one can use `chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry` to obtain a `fileSystem`-compatible readonly entry instead of using XHR.